# Is my toilet flange too high off the ground?

Tags: toilet, flange

[image]

Recently had my floors redone in a bathroom and the toilet flange seems to be a little high off the new tile floor. What are my options?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is close to 1 inch two high. The easiest option would be to cut it below the floor and put a coupling in then you can keep shaving it down until it is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If someone glued the flange in, then look at it from the bottom side to see if there is room to drop it to be flush with the floor. (This is your goal ) You don't want to over do it though. You need 1/4" per foot drain, so you need to see if there is flexibility there, and room enough to drop it without interfering with the drain 1/4 fall. There's a chance that you may need to change the current setup by cutting into the drain and put in a coupler. From there you can customize to fit the way it should be. Good luck!